# MDX query that returns how many female users of each country that liked certain product

Tags: mdx, pentaho, data-warehouse, olap, mondrian

I'm trying to create a MDX query to find how many female users of each country have liked a certain product. I'm now using this query

```
SELECT
{ COUNT([Users].[Id].Members, [Products].[Name].[ProductX] ) } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Countries].[Name].Members } ON ROWS
FROM [Likes]
WHERE ( [Gender].[Name].[Female] )
```

but it throws `Mondrian Error: No function matches signature 'COUNT(<Set>, <Member>)'`. I'm new to MDX and can't truly understand how I can use the count function correctly, and how to create this kind of query.

How should I make this query?

Answer (score 0):

try this query,

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Likes] } ON 0, COUNT(ORDER([Users].[ID].[Products].[Name].[ProductX].Members,[Measures].[Likes], DESC)) ON 1 FROM [Likes] WHERE ( [Gender].[Name].[Female] )
```

Comment: It throws a "Mondrian Error:MDX object '[Users].[ID].[Products].[Name].[ProductX]' not found in cube 'Likes'". Also, can I use .Members after [ProductX]? I thought that "[Products].[Name].[ProductX]" returned already a member.

Comment: just do appropriate changes according to your fields in table, because the query you tried has some basic mistakes. So that i suggested this.